# ValueError: Tensor is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, watchdog

At the moment I am testing some deep learning with TensorFlow and Keras. Now I would like to evaluate pictures. Therefore I need to know with help of the watchdog class if a new image is created in a folder. In this case I want to do a prediction. Therefore I need to load my trained deep learning model from a .json file first and initialize it with weights from an .h5 file. This step takes some time. Therefore I plan to load the model once and subsequently I would like to do many predictions. Unfortunately I got the following error message and I suggest something with the loaded_model went wrong.  If I load it for every prediction there is no problem but this way is not what I want.

```
#####     Prediction-Class     #####

#Import
from keras.models import model_from_json
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from PIL import Image


class PredictionClass():
    #loaded_model = self.LoadModel()
    counter = 0

    def Load_Model(self):
        modelbez = 'modelMyTest30'
        gewichtsbez = 'weightsMyTest30'

        # load json and create model
        print("Loading...")
        json_file = open(modelbez + '.json', 'r')
        loading_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        loading_model = model_from_json(loading_model_json)
        # load weights into new model
        loading_model.load_weights(gewichtsbez + ".h5")
        print('Loaded model from disk:' + 'Modell: ' + modelbez + 'Gewichte: ' + gewichtsbez)

        loading_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return loading_model

    def Predict(path, loaded_model):
         test_image = image.load_img(path, target_size = (64, 64))
         test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
         test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)

         # This step causes the error
         result = loaded_model.predict(test_image)
         print('Prediction successful')

         if result[0][0] == 1:
            prediction = 'schlecht'
            img = Image.open(path)
            img.save(path, "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
            #counterschlecht = counterschlecht +1

         else:
            prediction = 'gut'
            img = Image.open(path)
            img.save(path, "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
            #countergut = countergut +1  

         print("Image "+" contains: " + prediction);


#####     FileSystemWatcher     #####

#Import
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer  

#Class-Definition "MyFileSystemHandler"
class MyFileSystemHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, PredictionClass, loaded_model_Para):
        self.predictor = PredictionClass
        self.loaded_model= loaded_model_Para

    def on_created(self, event):
        #Without this wait-Step I got an Error "Permission denied
        time.sleep(10)
        PredictionClass.Predict(event.src_path, self.loaded_model)
        print('Predict')


#####     MAIN     #####

predictor = PredictionClass()
print('Class instantiated')
loaded_model_Erg = predictor.Load_Model()
print('Load Model')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyFileSystemHandler(predictor, loaded_model_Erg)

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop', recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        #Press Control + C to stop the FileSystemWatcher
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Error:

ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use keras model to predict from many threads, You should first call `model._make_predict_function` function before threading. You can find more on [here](https://github.com/jaara/AI-blog/blob/master/CartPole-A3C.py) and github issue [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6124).

```
predictor = PredictionClass()
print('Class instantiated')
loaded_model_Erg = predictor.Load_Model()
loaded_model_Erg._make_predict_function()
print('Load Model')
```